# Problems rendering in Kdenlive

Tags: kdenlive

So I have a basic Kdenlive project; HD 720p 24fps.

When I click render, everything starts okay but then it's finished after about 10 seconds and says everything was done successfully. However, when I go to play the video I get an error message, the video doesn't even have a thumbnail in nautilus.

I've tried rendering in many different profiles/combinations. Nothing is working.

What's going on? I've rendered videos in Kdenlive before, any ideas?

Ubuntu 12.10/latest version of Kdenlive

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I followed the information in the following link and it worked. I still have some audio issues in the rendered file, but at least now I can create a file from my project.

http://www.kdenlive.org/mantis/view.php?id=2592

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I don't know if the reason is the same or not
I found out, when I render my video with those title made in Kdenlive, it cannot render the video. I replaced those titles with png files (made in Gimp) and solved.

you can do one thing. just export 10 seconds (from different parts of your project. see where is there problem.

Answer (score 0):

One issue that most folks foreget is that Kdenlive requires Frei0r a cross platform video filter which some distibutions platforms foreget to include with Kdenlive.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).